# ADO Parallel Processing Performance Not Consistant for Matlab Job

Tags: matlab, azure-devops, parallel-processing, simulink, cicd

I set-up a build and testing CI pipeline using ADO, Matlab/Simulink & Windows self hosted agents. When we push, a build task is sent to a server, and a testing task is sent to 3 servers(of of which is the same as the build server) who have 3 agents each. So in total 9 git repos are downloaded and task are run on them. Scaling out we have server isolation, Scaling up I have file and job isolation. So at 1 time, 3 jobs run on 3 different agent file sandboxes on the same computer & this happens on 3 different computers. I ran around 100-200 MIL test, they take anywhere between 30 min to 1h on average to complete individually.When running in parallel, I've seen this in the best case drop down to 1.6 min per test(2nd picture). All test + build completing in 3 hours.

Now my issue, is that running the same exact pair of test on a different commit  When running in parallel, I've seen this in the worst case drop down to 6.6 min per test(3nd picture). All test + build completing in 10 hours.

Note:

1. I have seen these performance issues happening more often when I scale up, than when I scale out.
2. I have also added a delay of 5-15 min between jobs 1-9 to make sure that any jobs on the same computer starts a few min apart to mitigate the risk of concurrency issues.

Why is this happening, any suggestion to have more consistent and optimal performance?

I've shared some slides and pics about issue:

Slide 1: In blue our build and testing pipeline. In yellow, potentially scaling out using more of our teammates computers for parallel processing.

Picture 1: Best Result

Picture 2: Worst Result

[image: Parallel Processing Logic]
[image: CI pipeline test run - best performance]
[image: CI pipeline test run - long performance]

Answer (score 2):

Although multiple agents can be installed on one machine, this is not recommended. [Installing two or more agents on the same machine might adversely affect performance and the result of your pipelines.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install) We strongly suggest to only install one agent per machine.

[image]

When running parallel jobs using multiple agents on the same machine, the negative effects may occur more frequently.

In addition, the networks, CPU utilization and other performances of the agent machine itself also could affect the performance of pipeline jobs running on it.

---

**EDIT:**

As far as I know, there is no good way to optimize the performance when running multiple agents on the same machine.

Using multiple agents on the same machine normally can work well for running jobs that don't consume many shared resources on the agent machine. The jobs don't do much work on the agent machine itself.

However, for other cases, you might not be able to gain much efficiency by running multiple agents on the same machine. It might not be worthwhile for running jobs that consume much disk and I/O resources, such as jobs run build and test processes.

You might also run into problems if parallel jobs are using the same singleton tool deployment, such as some dependency packages. For example, one job might update a dependency while another job is in the middle of using it, which could cause unreliable results and errors.

Running each agent in a Docker container might avoid some of the performance problems. However, if you run multiple Docker containers on the same machine, you still need to consider the consumption of disk and I/O resources and other shared resources.

---

Comment: Thx for answering, even if it's not best practice is there anyway of optimizing the performance? Or is it random? From what I understand, could the performance be better if the agents where in docker nodes? If so why? What condition explain the best performance of 2h? I ask because I've seen other tool being able to scale up with good performance, what explain this ADO specific limitations?

Comment: @Weltgeist, I have updated my answer with more explanations (See **EDIT**). Hope this can help you understand deeper.